# Responsive background image - resize/rescale gradually

Tags: html, css

Is it possibly I can gradually rescale my background image.

Currently, media queries force it to jump from 900px to 300px height at a certain stage. How do I do this gradually?

http://jsfiddle.net/dq4gyduv/

```css
.hero {
    background:url('http://placehold.it/1400x900') center center no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    height:900px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .hero {
        height:300px
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
</div>
```

Comment: You can use percentages so 100% height will stay at what every it can get

Comment: Thank you. Could you possibly show me using my example how I can do this? It has to begin at 900px and be 300px at mobile, but I'd like the rest to just vary if possible.

Comment: Does it need to be a css background-image or can you use an `<img>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```css
.hero {
    background:url('http://placehold.it/1400x900') center center no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    height:900px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .hero {
           height: 300px;
           background-size: 100% auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ke4fsvw/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.container {
    height:900px;
}

.hero {
    background:url('http://placehold.it/1400x900') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero">
  </div>
</div>
```